# Drawing a Polyline that gradually fades out

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to draw a [`Polyline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) whose opacity gradually fades out as the trail progresses, mimicking the effect of a highlighter that runs out of ink. I first took a naive approach with a [`LinearGradientBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush();
lgb.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0), 0.0));
lgb.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0, 0), 1.0));
line.Stroke = lgb;
```

As you can see on the image below, that didn't quite work out for me. I drew two polylines starting from the position of the hand. Although the "Bottom Left" path is drawn correctly as a fade out, the "Top Left" path is drawn as a fade in, which is not what I want. It appears that the gradient's effect isn't applied in the way that I need it to be.

[image: Polyline rendering]

How can I draw a `Polyline` where the line gradually fades out as the path nears it end?

---

**Edit**: Here's a new approach to my problem that I'm currently exploring. If I use `PathGeometry`, can I set the brushes of individual segments of a line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [the GradientPath library](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/02/Graphical-Paths-with-Gradient-Colors.html), which lets me paint a gradient over a path in the way that I would like to use it. Here's a sample rendering.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to set the [StartPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush.startpointproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [EndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush.endpointproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties of the LinearGradientBrush to match the start / end points of your PolyLine.

Well, maybe not the exact values of the StartPoints / EndPoint but normalized values to match the slope of your line.

This only works for straight or almost straight PolyLines.

For example :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="lgb" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="lgb2" StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="lgb3" StartPoint="1,1" EndPoint="0,0">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Polyline Stroke="{StaticResource lgb}" StrokeThickness="10">
        <Polyline.Points>
            <Point X="150" Y="150"/>
            <Point X="300" Y="300"/>
        </Polyline.Points>
    </Polyline>

    <Polyline Stroke="{StaticResource lgb2}" StrokeThickness="10">
        <Polyline.Points>
            <Point X="150" Y="150"/>
            <Point X="0" Y="300"/>
        </Polyline.Points>
    </Polyline>

    <Polyline Stroke="{StaticResource lgb3}" StrokeThickness="10">
        <Polyline.Points>
            <Point X="150" Y="150"/>
            <Point X="140" Y="140"/>
        </Polyline.Points>
    </Polyline>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in my tests this stops working when a `Polyline` makes a U-turn. I tried it with these points: *(150, 150); (150, 50); (250, 50); (250, 150)*

Comment: You're right, this only works for straight PolyLines.. you may have to break your PolyLines into Lines..

Comment: I tried breaking up the `Polyline` into `Line`s before, but then the corners look weird if your stroke thickness value is bigger than 1.